# Relation of surface area of a sphere to its volume.

Tags: calculus, geometry

As I was working on a problem I noticed that the formula for the surface area of a sphere is the derivative of a sphere's volume with respect to $r$. Is this purely coincidental or is there a reason for this?

Comment: Look up $n$-sphere for your interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a coincidence. The same holds for circles - the circumference is the derivative of the area.

Start with a sphere of radius $r$. If the skin has thickness $dr$, the volume of the skin will be approximately $A.dr$, where $A$ is the surface area.

However, it will *also* be $V(r + dr) - V(r)$, so $$A\approx \frac{V(r+dr) - V(r)}{dr}$$

As $dr$ gets tiny, this gives $A=V^\prime(r)$.